# A solution to the "unexpected token U" error and a fix to the parseJSON function?

Tags: jquery

I see that many developers came across this issue. To fix the problem, however, I modified jquery 1.10.2.js script's source as follows:

The original starts the definition of function parseJSON as:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {

    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    if (data === null) {
        return data;
    }
         .
         .
         .
```

Now, I changed this code excerpt to the following:

```
parseJSON: function( data ) {

if (data === null || data === undefined) {
    return data;
}

// Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
if (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse) {
    return window.JSON.parse( data );
}
```

My change consists of:

1. changing the order of the 2 ifs
2. adding a check for undefined for "data"

I wonder why the if (data === null) clock is not the first - what's the point of verifying whether the browser supports/has a JSON.parse method before checking if the data is null - if it is null, you won't be able to parse it to anything else anyway!

This fix solves my problem, and I wonder why JQuery's code is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was done to bring `$.parseJSON` more inline with how `window.JSON.parse` works. If you wish to go back to the old way (by swapping those two lines), do it by monkey patching the method, not by changing the source.

```
(function($){
    var old = $.parseJSON;
    $.parseJSON = function(data){
        if (data === null || data === undefined) {
            return data;
        }
        return old.call($,data);
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Though, i wonder why they allow it to work with nulls in non window.JSON browsers. (this has since been changed, see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.x-master/src/ajax/parseJSON.js and https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/parseJSON.js)